# jQuery Append message to each label

Tags: jquery, append, each

When the check button is clicked a message is appended to the radio group checked radio button (correct or incorrect). I want the message to align with the selected radio button. At the moment both messages are applied to both checked radio buttons rather than the associated correct or incorrect.

How do I update this script so for correct check button correct message is applied and if incorrect the relevant message is applied?

Hopefully I am not being too confusing :-)

```
$(".quiz__check").on("click", function() {
  $("input:radio:checked").removeAttr("disabled");   
  if($("input:radio:checked").length > 0){
    $("input:radio:checked").addClass("mPos");;
    $("input:radio:checked").closest(".radio").find(".mPos + label").append( $('.quiz__control-feedback') );
  }
});
```

The HTML

```
<div id="accessContainer">
  <form class="quiz" id="a01" name="a01">
    <div class="quiz__preamble"></div>
    <ol class="assessment-list">
      <li>
        <span><strong>Question 1:</strong> What question is this?</span>
        <div></div>
        <div aria-label="When should you make adjustments to the program or environment?" class="quiz__control accessibleRadio" id="a01-01-q09" role="radiogroup">
          <p><input data-set="a01-01-q09" id="a01-q09-e01" name="a01-01-q09" type="radio" value="a01-01-q09"> <label for="a01-q09-e01">This is question 1</label></p>
          <p><input data-set="a01-01-q09" id="a01-q09-e02" name="a01-01-q09" type="radio" value="a01-01-q09"> <label for="a01-q09-e02">This is question 20</label></p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <span><strong>Question 2:</strong> Is this question 2?</span>
        <div></div>
        <div aria-label="When should you teach children about diversity and difference?" class="quiz__control accessibleRadio" id="a01-01-q11" role="radiogroup">
          <p><input data-set="a01-01-q11" id="a01-q11-e01" name="a01-01-q11" type="radio" value="a01-01-q11"> <label for="a01-q11-e01">Yes</label></p>
          <p><input data-set="a01-01-q11" id="a01-q11-e02" name="a01-01-q11" type="radio" value="a01-01-q11"> <label for="a01-q11-e02">No</label></p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <div class="quiz__buttons screen-only">
      <button class="quiz__reset btn btn-default" title="Clear my answers" type="reset">Reset</button> <button class="quiz__check btn btn-primary" id="check_answers" title="Check my answers" type="button">Check</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is a *«hard»* mess... Check it. I had strange taughts trying to indent it. Think container. Like Tupperwares. Your ending tags are at wrong places. --- Sorry, this comments isn't adressisng the issue.. but the question formatting. Be you programmer.. Indents your code. It save debugging.

Comment: Thanks Louys. I'll reformat the HTML and reapply it.

Comment: HTML checked and re-formatted :-)

Comment: What message? *«I want the message to align with the selected radio button»* --- [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/yXbpdb)

Comment: I'm really messing this up. When the button is pressed a correct or incorrect message displays under the radio group. I want it to display next to the selected radio button instead.

Comment: Closing because I need to ask this in a better way.

Comment: Actually, there must be something missing in the code you posted, because there is no message shown. It may be `.quiz__control-feedback`, but I can't say. There is nothing to determine if the answer is correct or not. Here is [something I've done fast](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/OgmKWd) which is what I think you want.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette That works. Thank you so much.

Comment: I posted it as an answer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a "validation message" to appear on `Check` click.
And you want it aside the radios, on the right (so after the `label`).

I added a `data` attribute to all your HTML radio `input`.
Got to know wich is correct and not...

```
data-validation="1" // for good answer

data-validation="0" // for wrong answer
```

Some CSS for the message formatting:

```
.validation-hint{
  margin-left:1em;
  font-style:bold;
}
.correct{
  color:#44c744;
}
.incorrect{
  color:#F74444;
}
```

Then here is the code to make it appear:

```
$(".quiz__check").on("click", function() {
  var checked = $("input[type='radio']:checked");
  var correct = "<span class='validation-hint correct'>Correct!</span>";
  var incorrect = "<span class='validation-hint incorrect'>Incorrect!</span>";

  if(checked.length > 0){

    // Remove all validation hints, if any.
    $(".validation-hint").remove();

    // Show a validation message based on data-validation.
    checked.each(function(){
      if( $(this).data("validation")=="1" ){
        $(this).next("label").after(correct);
      }else{
        $(this).next("label").after(incorrect);
      }
    })
  }
});

// Reset button also remove the validation messages.
$("[type='reset']").on("click",function(){
  // Remove all validation hints
    $(".validation-hint").remove();
});
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/OgmKWd)